# Triple integral to find the volume of a solid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question is: Find the volume of the solid in the first octant bounded by $x+y+z=1$ and $x+y+2z=1$.

$x+y+z=1$ is $z=1-x-y$ and $x+y+2z=1$ is $z=1/2-x/2-y/2$.

Graphically these are two planes that intersect each other.

Looking at the graph I get: $1/2-x/2-y/2\le z\le 1-x-y$.

To get the y's bounds I did: $x+y+z=1$ is $y=1-x-z$, so using $z=1/2-x/2-y/2$ to substitute, I got $y=1-x-1/2-x/2-y/2$. This equals $y=1-x$. So for my y's bounds I have $0\le y\le 1-x$.

I know that y and x are bounded by $0$ on the left because it is the first octant. I planned on doing $\int\int\int dzdydx$.

I am not sure if my bounds are correct so far or how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you need, has been noted by @user69810. Note that, without drawing a nice picture as follows, you may miss good solving points for the question.

[image]

In fact, as you see, $0\leq x\leq 1$ is for our free variable, $0\leq y\leq 1-x$ and as you noted $$1/2-x/2-y/2\le z\le 1-x-y$$

Answer (score 1):

This becomes easier if you draw a picture. The two planes can be drawn easily if you user the x, y and z intercepts.

For example, $x+y+z=1$ contains the three points (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1). Do the same for the other plane. You will see that $x+y+2z=1$ is below $x+y+z=1$ and so the volume you are calculating is a relatively simple wedge shape. You should now be able to set your limits of integration and proceed.

Comment: I have it drawn...I am not sure if my y bounds are correct or how to find the x bounds.

Comment: In the z direction, go from the bottom plane to the top plane. In the x and y directions just go from 0 to 1. Another way is to do the same thing but use each plane separately and subtract the answer you get for the bottom one from the answer you get from the top one.

Comment: Both y and x cannot be bounded by a number on the right. That would imply that they are bounded at the right by a constant, which they are not.

Comment: The above x and y directions in the last comment are incorrect. The two planes intersect at $x+y=1$ so if you integrate in the y direction before the x direction, you go from 0 to 1 - x and then from 0 to 1.

Comment: How did you get $y=1-x$?

Comment: Never mind, I see my mistake...How did you get 0 to 1 though?

Comment: The last one is always constant. This happens because by the time we get to the last one we are already constrained in the other dimensions.

Comment: I know that...how did you find its value though.

Comment: I got the value from the intercepts. Imagine viewing the volume from above and looking down.